# golan-gin api return invalid URL escape %

Tags: go

I want to create an api for uploading images in my go-gin application. This is my current api code :

```
func (s *Service) ImageCreate(c *gin.Context) {
    token := c.MustGet(tokenKey).(*models.Token)
    now := time.Now()

    file, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": "01> " + err.Error()})
        return
    }
}
```

When I call my application from the browser it returns this error:

```
{"error":"01\u003e invalid URL escape \"%$\\xf4\""}
```

In postman api it's working without error. What is wrong? How I can fix it for the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Postman.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/server-image/upload-file -F "file=@/Users/shikuanxu/Downloads/images/course-outline.png" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```

Try again